# __get__ of descriptor __class__ of object class doesn't return as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to understand more thoroughly descriptor and explicit attribute name look-up order.
I read [descriptor howto](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) and it states as follows:

> The details of invocation depend on whether obj is an object or a class:
>       ...
>   For classes, the machinery is in `type.__getattribute__`() which transforms `B.x` into `B.__dict__['x'].__get__(None, B)`

I test this on `__class_`_ since it is a data descriptor of `object`

```
In [47]: object.__class__
Out[47]: type
```

So, it returns `type` as expected since `type` class creates all classes including `object` class. Base on the 'descriptor howto', `object.__class__` is turned into `object.__dict__['__class__'].__get__(None, object)`.
However, When I run it, the output is the descriptor itself, not `type`

```
In [48]: object.__dict__['__class__'].__get__(None, object)
Out[48]: <attribute '__class__' of 'object' objects>
```

I guess it returns the descriptor itself because inside of this `__get__` having some kind of code like:

```
if instance is None:
    return self
```

So, I understand the reason of returning the descriptor itself when calling from class. The thing confuses me is the different ouputs

When it says '`B.x` into `B.__dict__['x'].__get__(None, B)`', I expect outputs are the same. Why are they different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The descriptor how-to is a simplification. It glosses over things like metaclasses, and the fact that classes are objects. Classes are objects, and they go through both "object-style" *and* "class-style" attribute lookup and descriptor handling. (The implementation can be found in [`type_getattro`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.2/Objects/typeobject.c#L3140), if you want to independently verify this.)

A lookup for `object.__class__` doesn't just go through `object.__mro__`; it also looks through `type(object).__mro__`. Descriptors found in `type(object).__mro__` use "object-style" descriptor handling, treating the class as an instance of its metaclass, while descriptors found in `object.__mro__` use "class-style" descriptor handling.

When you look up `object.__class__`, Python searches through `type(object).__mro__`. Since `object` is in `type(object).__mro__`, this search finds `object.__dict__['__class__']`. Since `object.__dict__['__class__']` is a *data descriptor* (it has a `__set__`), this takes priority over the search through `object.__mro__`. Thus, treating `object` as an instance of `object` rather than as a class, Python performs

```
descr.__get__(object, type(object))
```

instead of

```
descr.__get__(None, object)
```

and the `__get__` call returns `type(object)`, which is `type`.

Your manual `descr.__get__(None, object)` call treats `object` as a class instead of as an instance of `object`. Invoked this way, the descriptor returns itself.

---

To demonstrate that `__class__` isn't being special-cased here, we can create our *own* class that's an instance of itself, just like `object` is:

```
class DummyMeta(type):
    pass

class SelfMeta(type, metaclass=DummyMeta):
    @property
    def x(self):
        return 3

SelfMeta.__class__ = SelfMeta

print(SelfMeta.x)
print(SelfMeta.__dict__['x'].__get__(None, SelfMeta))
print(SelfMeta.__dict__['x'].__get__(SelfMeta, type(SelfMeta)))
```

Output:

```
3
<property object at 0x2aff9f04c5e8>
3
```

Just like with `object.__class__`, "object-style" descriptor handling happens here too. (Also, in case you're wondering, properties are data descriptors even if you don't write a setter.)

Comment: So this means that all data descriptors of `object` always go through "object-style" invocation since `object in type(object).__mro__`. And the same applies to `type` since `type in type(type).__mro__`. In the end the descriptor how-to just misses to mention that "object-style" invocation takes precedence over "class-style" invocation (which would resolve the ambiguity for classes).

Comment: After playing with a few examples of class and metaclass, I think I understand your answer now. Thanks a lot

Comment: @a_guest: I think the same applies to `type`. I checked on `type.__name__`. It returns `type` the same as `type.__dict__['__name__'].__get__(type, type(type))`. While `type.__dict__['__name__'].__get__(None, type)` returns the descriptor itself.

Comment: Very elegant demonstration. The key is that `type` is a subclass of `object`. There is no special lookup for `object.__class__` like one might initially think, the classes of the method resolution order of the metaclass `type(object)` is looked up like usual.